# React routing changes URL but doesn't load component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use react-router in my app to change a component but doesn't load unless URL is changing.
I use react-router 5.2.0 and react 16.13.1. I've try to use this code https://codesandbox.io/s/14y47028jl?file=/ProductHistory.js:1128-1174 but it doesn't work.

This is my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-dew-t3pbb When I click on the Contact link URL changes but view doesn't

Comment: I tried the above link and it seems to be working

Comment: The code seems working. What issue are you facing?

Comment: Code in the sandbox appears to function correctly. Other than usage of deprecated react lifecycle functions what, if any, errors, warnings, or issues are you seeing?

Comment: I have no errors or warnings just the component doesn't change